# Looping through specific subfolders in outlook containing a specific string

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to look for specific items inside specific subfolders in Outlook (macro VBA) that can be in first or second level subfolder, however I cannot make it to work. I have found other questions that loop through all the items in all folders, but not that go through all items in specific subfolders.

```
fldrname = "Clearing"
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ClearingFolders = Outlook.Folders("Clearing", objNS.Folders)
    For Each ClearingFolders In objParentFolderCollection
        For Each folder In ClearingFolders
            If InStr(1, fldrname, folder.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                {findEmail}
            End If
        Next folder`
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how to access every mail item within every folder, and sub-folder to any depth, within a parent folder.  It does this by outputting an indented list of items and sub-folders to the Immediate Window.  The format of the output is:

```
ParentFolderName
  Date Subject (of mail item within ParentFolder
  Date Subject (of mail item within ParentFolder
  Date Subject (of mail item within ParentFolder
  ChildFolder1Name
  Date Subject (of mail item within ChildFolder1Name
  Date Subject (of mail item within ChildFolder1Name
  GrandchildFolder1Name
    Date Subject (of mail item within GrandchildFolder1Name
    Date Subject (of mail item within GrandchildFolder1Name
  ChildFolder2Name
    Date Subject (of mail item within ChildFolder2Name
    Date Subject (of mail item within ChildFolder2Name
    GrandchildFolder2Name
      Date Subject (of mail item within GrandchildFolder2Name
      Date Subject (of mail item within GrandchildFolder2Name
      GreatgrandchildFolder1Name
        Date Subject (of mail item within GreatgrandchildFolder1Name
        Date Subject (of mail item within GreatgrandchildFolder1Name
  ChildFolder3Name
      :  :  :  :  :
```

There are statements within your code I do not understand so I have ignored your code and created my own.

Consider first:

```
Set Fldr = Session.Folders("StoreName").Folders("TopLevelFolderName")
```

Your equivalent of this statement is:

```
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = objNS.Folders("StoreName").Folders("TopLevelFolderName")
```

With VBA there is often more than one way of achieving the same effect.  I prefer `Session` to `objNS`.  My code so my favourites.  Change to your favourite if you wish.

A store is a file on disc that Outlook uses to hold mail items, tasks, appointment items and so on.    I assume “Clearing” is the name of a folder and not the name of a store.  Your folder pane will look something like this:

```
StoreName1
  Clearing1
  Deleted Items
  Inbox
  Sent Items
StoreName2
   Inbox
     Clearing2
  Sent
  Trash
```

You can have as many stores as you wish.  There will be one per email address and perhaps one for archives.  When I change computers, I add my old stores to my new Outlook installation, so I have access to all my old emails.

It seems there is always an “Inbox”.  Other standard folders change their names from version to version so you might have “Deleted Items” or “Trash” or something else.  You can add your own folders wherever you like.

If your “Clearing” is a store, you will need:

```
Set Fldr = Session.Folders("Clearing")
```

If your “Clearing” is at the same level as “Inbox” like my “Clearing1”, you will need:

```
Set Fldr = Session.Folders("StoreName1").Folders("Clearing1")
```

If your “Clearing” is under “Inbox” like my “Clearing2”, you will need:

```
Set Fldr = Session.Folders("StoreName2").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Clearing2")
```

Change my statement to match your system.

Notice that I write:

```
Dim Fldr As Outlook.Folder
```

but

```
Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
```

This code runs under Outlook so I do not need to specific Outlook.  I could have written `Outlook.MailItem` but it would not add value because VBA only has one data type named `MailItem`.  However, Outlook as two data types `Folder`; one for disc folders and one for Outlook folders.  Outlook VBA will assume you mean `Outlook.Folder` when you write `Folder` but I once got myself into a muddle when I did not specify which `Folder` I meant.  Now, I am always careful to write `Outlook.Folder` or `Scripting.Folder` so I will not forget when it is important.

The sub `ProcessChild` is recursive.  There are excellent explanations of recursion on the web so I will not attempt my own explanation now.  However, if you are confused, I will add an explanation of my routine.

Now consider:

```
For InxI = 1 To FldrPrnt.Items.Count
  :  :  :
For InxF = 1 To FldrPrnt.Folders.Count
```

You have used `For Each`.  I sometimes use `For Each` but I find `For Index` more convenient most of the time.

`FldrPrnt` is the folder whose mail items and sub-folders I wish to access.  `FldrPrnt.Items` gives me access to the items and `FldrPrnt.Folders` gives me access to the sub-folders.

When I write `For InxI = 1 To FldrPrnt.Items.Count`, I access the items oldest first.  If I had written `For InxI = FldrPrnt.Items.Count to 1 Step -1`, I would have accessed the items newest first.  “Oldest” and “Newest” here does not refer to the date of the item.  It refers to the order in which items were added to `FldrPrnt.Items`.  Normally mail items are added in date order so these two orders are the same.  However, if you accidentally delete an old mail item then move it back from folder “Deleted Items”, it will become the newest item in the folder.

Often you can write either `For InxI = 1 To FldrPrnt.Items.Count` or `For InxI = FldrPrnt.Items.Count to 1 Step -1`.  However, if your processing involves moving items to another folder, you must use `FldrPrnt.Items.Count to 1 Step -1`.  With `For Index`, you are identifying items by their position within `FldrPrnt.Items`.  If you move item 20 to another folder, item 21 becomes item 20, item 22 becomes item 21 and so on.  For the next repeat of the loop, you will check the new item 21 not the old item 21.  We sometimes get questions where someone is only checking half their items.  This is the reason.

Notice `If TypeName(FldrPrnt.Items(InxI)) = "MailItem" Then`.   Not every item is a MailItem.  It is essential to check an item’s type before processing it since different items have different properties.

I hope the above, is enough for you to understand my code but ask question is necessary.  All my code does is display the received time and subject of each mail item.  You will have to replace my `Debug.Print` statement with whatever code you need to achieve your objectives.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()

  Dim Fldr As Outlook.Folder

  Set Fldr = Session.Folders("StoreName").Folders("TopLevelFolderName")

  Call ProcessChild(Fldr, 0)

End Sub
Sub ProcessChild(ByRef FldrPrnt As Outlook.Folder, ByVal Indent As Long)

  Dim InxF As Long
  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Debug.Print Space(Indent * 2) & FldrPrnt.Name

  For InxI = 1 To FldrPrnt.Items.Count
    If TypeName(FldrPrnt.Items(InxI)) = "MailItem" Then
      Set ItemCrnt = FldrPrnt.Items(InxI)
      With ItemCrnt
        Debug.Print Space(Indent * 2 + 2) & .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
      End With
    End If
  Next
  For InxF = 1 To FldrPrnt.Folders.Count
    If FldrPrnt.Folders(InxF).DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
      Call ProcessChild(FldrPrnt.Folders(InxF), Indent + 1)
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Tony, 

I forgot to thank you for the nice and complete answer. 

One thing I do not understand, is the "For index to" faster/better than the "For each" loop?

Comment: @Mogambo  You are welcome.  I still remember learning Outlook VBA without an adequate guide.  I bought a recommended book but I found it of little value.  Almost everything I know was the result of careful experimentation.

Comment: I do not know if one of `For Each` or `For Index` is slightly faster than the other.  If you are worried about saving milliseconds, VBA is not the language for you.  If you are writing a transaction processor that will process millions or billions of transactions per day, every millisecond counts so spending an extra half-an-hour optimising the code is worth it.  But if you are writing a macro that will be run once or twice per day, those milliseconds will never add up to the extra time it took to write the code.

Comment: I use whichever of `For Each` and `For Index` I find most convenient at the time.  I use `For Index` more that `For Each` but that could be because the languages I first used did not have `For Each`.  I probably prefer `For Index` because I have used it for over 50 years.

Comment: With Excel, including `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and avoiding `Select` can save a lot of time.  With Outlook, you can sort the items within a folder by most properties or you can restrict the items you see to those that are of interest.  This type of functionality can save enough run time to be worth the programming time.  I was taught: “Get it working then make it better, faster, smaller.”  That is still my guiding philosophy when designing and writing code.

Comment: If my answer helped, please click the tick at the top to accept it.  This indicates to future visitors that this answer was helpful.

Comment: thanks again!
Well my code is running but it needs to loop through around 400 emails in diferent stores and diferent subfolders until it finds in which folder it is (Total item loop could be up to around 5000). I already set up the property of the day (as I know when it arrived, but not where)  so the total amount of items gets filtered.
It works in developing, but whern it has to loop through the stores, then the subfolders, then the items, it crashes Outlook. Do you have any idea there?

Comment: @Mogambo  I have code that loops through many stores and many folders without problems.  Please provide information on the nature of the crash.

Comment: when I execute my code, after a while of running trying to find the requested string in the comments section, Otlook stops responding and has to be restarted.
For the loop I first restrict the stack of mails by date and then loop through them calling the MailItem.PropertyAccessor to read the comments. If it is not found it goes to the next subfolder, if not found, goes to the next store.

Comment: @Mogambo.  I have never tried accessing comments of which there seem to be several types.  Which comments are you accessing?  What proptag-specifier are you using?  I have used MailItem.PropertyAccessor when looping over large numbers of MailItems without problems.  It might help if you include more of your code in your question.  It is possible that this should be a new question.  You can ask as many questions as you like but each question should only be about one topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572445/looping-through-mailitems-in-outlook-macro-freezes-outlook-in-large-sets-of-mail

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all folders recursively:

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Also, you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

Read more about the AdvancedSearch method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

So, maybe you don't need to iterate over all folders and search for specific items there any longer?