# Looping through large set of mailitems freezes Outlook

Tags: vba, performance, outlook

I am trying to loop through the mailItems of different subfolders looking for a comment (with PropertyAccessor) in different stores.

My code works when given 1-3 stores and around 2000 mailItems, however as the number increases it crashes Outlook.

I have implemented:

- Date filtering
- MailItem release

I am trying parallely the `Application.AdvancedSearch` method, however not managing yet.

```vb
Sub FindEmaibyComment()

  Dim Fldr As Outlook.folder
  Dim Str As Outlook.Store
  Dim Strs As Outlook.Stores
  Dim Pfldr As Outlook.folder
  Dim oRoot As Outlook.folder
  Dim clearingFolder As Outlook.folder
  Dim mail As MailItem
  Dim TaskID As String
  
  Set Strs = Application.Session.Stores
  
  TaskID = InputBox("Enter the MailID you want to look for." & vbNewLine & "(For example MAIL_20200525_1502769)", "Message input", "")
  Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With RegEx
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "MAIL_" & "[0-9]{8}" & "_" & "[0-9]{6,100}" ' <-- Regex match for input string, example string: MAIL_20200513_1434402
  End With

  Set Match = RegEx.Execute(TaskID)

  If Match.Count = 1 Then
 
    'Select the stores that contain ICE, and loop through them
    For Each Str In Strs
        If InStr(Str.DisplayName, "Mailbox1") > 0 Then 
            On Error Resume Next '--> In case no permission for the store is given, go to the next store
            Set oRoot = Str.GetRootFolder
            Set clearingFolder = LoopFolders(oRoot, TaskID)
        End If
    Next Str
    If MailFound = False Then
        MsgBox ("Sorry, I could not find the Email")
    End If
    
  Else
    MsgBox ("Please insert the correct ID with a format as follows: MAIL_12345678_1234567")
  End If

End Sub

Function LoopFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.folder, TaskID As String) As Outlook.folder
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders
 Dim Subfolders As Outlook.folders
 Dim folder As Outlook.folder
 Dim SubFolder As Outlook.folder
 Dim foldercount As Integer
 Dim clearingFolder As Outlook.folder
 
 On Error Resume Next
 Set folders = oFolder.folders
 foldercount = folders.Count

 'Count folders below oFolder. This is the store level
 If foldercount Then
     For Each folder In folders
          
          'Count folders below Folder. This is 1. folder level "AE01"
        If folder.folders.Count > 0 Then
            Set Subfolders = folder.folders

            For Each SubFolder In Subfolders
            
            'Subfolders below Folder. This is 2. folder level "Clearing", "Destination"
                If InStr(SubFolder, "Destination") > 0 Then
                    Set LoopFolders = SubFolder
                    FindID TaskID, SubFolder

                End If
            Next SubFolder
        End If
    Next folder
 End If
End Function

Function FindID(TaskID As String, folderClearing As Outlook.folder)

 Dim PropName, Comment, MessageID As String
 Dim oMail As MailItem
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
 Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim inputDate, inputDay, inputYear, inputMonth, sFilter, inputDateConverted, startDay, endDay As String

    inputDate = Right(Left(TaskID, 13), 8)  'Example: 20200610
    inputYear = Left(inputDate, 4)
    inputDay = Right(inputDate, 2)
    inputMonth = Right(Left(inputDate, 6), 2)

    If Left(inputDay, 1) = "0" Then
        inputDay = Right(inputDay, 1)
    End If
    If Left(inputMonth, 1) = "0" Then
        inputMonth = Right(inputMonth, 1)
    End If

    inputDateConverted = inputMonth & "/" & inputDay & "/" & inputYear
    startDay = Format(CDate(inputDateConverted & " 00:00 AM "), "\'m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM\'")
    endDay = Format(CDate(inputDateConverted & " 12:00 PM"), "\'m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM\'")
    
    Set myItems = folderClearing.Items
    sFilter = startDay & " > [ReceivedTime] And" & endDay & " < [ReceivedTime]"
    Set myRestrictedItems = myItems.Restrict(sFilter)

 For Each oMail In myRestrictedItems
    'PR_TRANSPORT_COMMENTS
    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3004001F"
    Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor
    Comment = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)
            
    If InStr(1, Comment, TaskID, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MailFound = True
        MsgBox ("Mail was found in Company Code " & folderClearing.Parent & ", let me open it for you")
        oMail.Display
        End
    End If
    Set oMail = Nothing

 Next oMail
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods are run on the main thread which means they block the UI and the overall user experience with Outlook. Moreover, iterating over all folder and subfolders is not really a good idea for searching items. That is for `AdvancedSearch` was introduced!

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Using the `Scope` parameter, you can specify one or more folders in the same store, but you may not specify multiple folders in multiple stores. To specify multiple folders in the same store for the `Scope` parameter, use a comma character between each folder path and enclose each folder path in single quotes. For default folders such as `Inbox` or `Sent Items`, you can use the simple folder name instead of the full folder path.

You can run multiple searches simultaneously by calling the AdvancedSearch method in successive lines of code. However, you should be aware that programmatically creating a large number of search folders can result in significant simultaneous search activity that would affect the performance of Outlook, especially if Outlook conducts the search in online Exchange mode.

```
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean  
  
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)  
    If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then  
        m_SearchComplete = True  
    End If  
End Sub  
  
Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()  
    Dim Scope As String  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search  
    Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row  
    m_SearchComplete = False  
    'Establish scope for multiple folders  
    Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderInbox).FolderPath _  
    & "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"  
    'Establish filter  
    If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"  
    Else  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"  
    End If  
    Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch( _  
    Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")  
    While m_SearchComplete <> True  
        DoEvents  
    Wend  
    Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable  
    Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable  
        Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as I mentioned that is the option I am trying to implement however I am having trouble 
1. checking the comment section: for subject it is easy, but for comments ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3004001F") does not seem to work
2. Extracting the results: The result should be only 1 MailItem, and I do not know how to get it ot of the variable Outlook.Search

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of mysterious failure is hiding errors with `On Error Resume Next`.

```
For Each Str In Strs
    
    Debug.Print "Str.DisplayName: " & Str.DisplayName
        
    If InStr(Str.DisplayName, "Mailbox1") > 0 Then
            
        Set oRoot = Nothing ' else bypssing expected error keeps previous value in oRoot
            
        ' bypass expected error
        On Error Resume Next '--> In case no permission for the store is given, go to the next store
        Set oRoot = Str.GetRootFolder
            
        ' remove error bypass
        '  to return to normal error handling
        '  to deal with unexpected errors
        On Error GoTo 0    ' now you can see errors and can debug your code

        ' Handle the bypassed error
        If Not oRoot Is Nothing Then
            Set clearingFolder = LoopFolders(oRoot, TaskID)
        End If
            
    End If
        
Next Str
```